# How to Export Multiple Tables to Multiple Worksheets Inside a Single Excel File

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to export multiple tables data to multiple Excel Sheets (Worksheets) inside single excel file using ASP.Net MVC. Records of each Table will be exported to a different Sheet (Worksheet) of an Excel file using ClosedXml library in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: Is there anything that is blocking you to implement that? If you face any issues with your current implementation, please update your question with the details of the code that you have tried along with the issue details.

Comment: Check this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-and-import-excel-file-using-closedxml-in-asp-net-mvc/

Here "Export Data to Excel with ClosedXML" section of above example, check line no 25.  wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);  here wb is workbook i.e. excel file. inside you are adding dt as worksheet. you can add as many worksheets as you want. try it and share code if you face any difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Use [OpenXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)

I created a dataset and under this dataset I added some tables. You can add your database tables to this dataset.

Here's my full code:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace MultipleWorksheet
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = null;

            try
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var excel = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, true))
                    {
                        workbookPart = excel.AddWorkbookPart();
                        workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                        uint sheetId = 1;
                        excel.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();
                        Sheets sheets = excel.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();

                        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                            dataTable.TableName = "Table" + (i + 1).ToString();

                            dataTable.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
                            dataTable.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
                            dataTable.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));
                            dataTable.Columns.Add("Column4", typeof(string));
                            dataTable.Columns.Add("Column5", typeof(string));


                            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                            {
                                DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                                for (int k = 0; k < dataTable.Columns.Count; k++)
                                {
                                    dataRow[k] = "Row" + (j + 1).ToString() + ", " + "Column" + (k + 1).ToString();
                                }

                                dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                            }

                            dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                           
                        }


                        for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables.Count; i++)
                        {
                            string relationshipId = "rId" + (i + 1).ToString();
                            WorksheetPart wSheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>(relationshipId);
                            string sheetName = dataSet.Tables[i].TableName;
                            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = sheetName };
                            sheets.Append(sheet);

                            Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet();

                            wSheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;

                            SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
                            worksheet.Append(sheetData);

                            string[] excelColumns = new string[] {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G" };

                            for (int l = 0; l < dataSet.Tables[i].Rows.Count; l++)
                            {
                                for (int m = 0; m < dataSet.Tables[i].Columns.Count; m++)
                                {
                                    AddToCell(sheetData,Convert.ToUInt32(l+1), excelColumns[m], CellValues.String, Convert.ToString(dataSet.Tables[i].Rows[l][m]));
                                }
                            }

                           
                            sheetId++;
                        }


                        excel.Close();
                    }

                    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "MultipleWorkSheet.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                    memoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
                    fileStream.Close();
                    memoryStream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }


        }


        private static void AddToCell(SheetData sheetData, UInt32 uint32rowIndex, string strColumnName, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue<CellValues> CellDataType, string strCellValue)
        {
            Row row = new Row() { RowIndex = uint32rowIndex };
            Cell cell = new Cell();

            cell = new Cell();
            cell.CellReference = strColumnName + row.RowIndex.ToString();
            cell.DataType = CellDataType;
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(strCellValue);
            row.AppendChild(cell);

            sheetData.Append(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be download multiple worksheet in one excel file. Is it?

Comment: it is not working I need the function that is called multiple tables download in single excel file.

Comment: you said, multiple worksheets!!! its just query. You can form a datatable based on your query and download into worksheet. thats it.